# Instapy "Invalid Like Element!"

Tags: python, instapy

I'm getting the following message when I run:

```
instapy: "Invalid Like Element!"
```

My code is

```
from instapy import InstaPy

insta_username = 'username'
insta_password = 'password'


session = InstaPy(username=insta_username, password=insta_password)
session.login()

session.set_delimit_commenting(enabled=True, max_comments=50000, min_comments=0)
session.set_do_comment(enabled=True, percentage=50)
session.set_comments(['comment1', 'comment2'])

session.like_by_tags(['tag1','tag2'], amount=40)



session.end()
```

I think the problem is in xpath_compile.py from InstaPy. At this moment my xpath_compile is set like:

```
`xpath["like_image"] = {
    "like": "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button[*[local-name()='svg']/@aria-label='Like']",
    "unlike": "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]/button[*[local-name()='svg']/@aria-label='Unlike']",
}`
```

[Here the error obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEMj0.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you include a larger snippet of the code? With this it's not clear what call is being made to trigger your error

Comment: Sure @PirateNinjas. I tried to explain better  now. Thanks

Comment: it is related to this issue: https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/5287 but none of the answers worked for me

Comment: Same with me. I think Instagram changed the HTML again.

Comment: //button/div/*[name()='svg'][@aria-label='Like']

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/instapy/xpath_compile.py
replace xpath["like_image"] section with:

```
xpath["like_image"] = {
    "like": "//section/span/button/div[*[local-name()='svg']/@aria-label='Like']",
    "unlike": "//section/span/button/div[*[local-name()='svg']/@aria-label='Unlike']",
}
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Instagram updated their HTML again as of July 28th, 2020. The correct X-Path should be:

```
xpath["like_image"] = {
    "like": "//section/span/button/div/span[*[local-name()='svg']/@aria-label='Like']",
    "unlike": "//section/span/button/div/span[*[local-name()='svg']/@aria-label='Unlike']",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks Instagram has modified the html.

In the xpath_compile.py file replace xpath["like_image"]

Remove:

```
xpath["like_image"] = {
    "like": "//section/span/button[*[local-name()='svg']/@aria-label='Like']",
    "unlike": "//section/span/button[*[local-name()='svg']/@aria-label='Unlike']",
}
```

Replace with:

```
xpath["like_image"] = {
    "like": "//section/span/button/div[*[local-name()='svg']/@aria-label='Like']",
    "unlike": "//section/span/button/div[*[local-name()='svg']/@aria-label='Unlike']",
}
```